# Excel lookup by minimum value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, lookup

I have this table:

[image: table].

Is it possible to look up the letter grade by the minimum percent value?
For example, anything greater than or equal to `87%` but less than `90%` returns `B+`.

Comment: if you could just search on google your title to this question; you wouldn't have to ask it here :) Please do proper research before posting a question.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @Sanu_012. I did attempt this. And while I am pretty fluent with formulas, I did not know the LOOKUP function supports this natively. So, I ignored pages about it, hence not finding the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{0,30,70,80,87,90,99}%,{"F","D","C","B-","B+","A"})
```

[image]

You can modify the parameters in the formula to change the values corresponding to the other ranges.

Comment: I had no idea the LOOKUP function will treat the values as the low of a range. Thank you.